# CodeIgniter .htaccess remove index.php on Server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I know there's a lot of questions and answers here but I'm really confused and I couldn't fix my problem yet. Please help!

I can easily access my controller via this url:

http://www.example.com/new/index.php/welcome

but I can't get it via this URL:
http://www.example.com/new/welcome

I'm configuring my CodeIgniter site in a subdirectory "new" and on my server, my directory structure is:

```
/  
   htdocs
       new
```

/ (this is empty), htdocs(here is my directory named as "new" and new(this is the exact folder where I've my codeIgniter files.
I'm confused here about "/" and "htdocs", I think this is the thing which I'm not able to handle because my domain example.com is pointing to htdocs i.e if I put index.php in htdocs, example.com will load index.php.

my .htaccess file in "new" directory is :

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1
```

in config/config.php:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

I've tried `$config['uri_protocol']`    for "Auto", "REQUEST_URI" and "QUERY_STRING" etc.

With this configuration I'm able to remove index.php in my local host but I can't fix it on server. Please help!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look to this page http://www.htaccessredirect.net/

Comment: i forgot: $config['index_page'] = ''; 
dont leave blank spaces

Comment: there's no white space... mate please help me..
my server is fasthosts

Comment: try with my response

Comment: I've tried all steps as you described in your response but no effect.

Comment: do you have the mod_rewrite enabled? if it is, the problem is that your rewrite base should be /new/

Comment: I've also tried RewriteBase /new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this one worked for me

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

make sure to remove index.php from appliation/config/config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Answer (score 2):

put this code in `.htaccess` file inside `new` directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

And dont forget to remove whitespace from:

`$config['index_page'] = ' ';`

Comment: no effect... same problem.. there's no whitespace in the above line specified by you.

Comment: whitespace between the quotations mate `' '`

Comment: no there's no whitespaces. It is as :
$config['index_page'] = '';

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code in .htaccess :

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: sorry, no effect. same problem.

Comment: Try with : RewriteBase /new. I hope this will be work for you.

Comment: again no effect. Don't know how to fix it :\

Comment: Did you do any changes in your config file?

Comment: no, I just downloaded the codeIgniter, install it on my local PC, it works great, then I uploaded it to server and now I'm facing this issue.

Comment: Did you check mod_rewrite enable on your server?

Comment: sorry, I don't know where to check that. I've echo phpinfo(); in my welcome view but I can't find that.

Answer (score 1):

Try either changing the

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';`
```

or changing the rewrite rule to use the query string instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?$1
```

Then setting the protocol to query string:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';`
```

Answer (score 1):

If you say that it's working on localhost, then it might be a server problem. Check if the server mod_rewrite is on by writing `phpinfo();` somewhere in your view code. If it's not on and you don't have permissions, contact your host admin.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

And the config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **?** after index.php in htaccess,

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```